# Program to automatically extract the slides from a video

Tags: windows, video

I have a video that presents a bunch of slides (e.g. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6V7WOMICC08). I would like to get the slides from it.  I am therefore looking for a program that would:

- automatically automatically extract the slides from a video
- can take several videos as input

And if possible:

- works on Windows 7
- free
- with GUI

It seems to be more or less possible using [ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12100266/395857), but I hope there exist other tools for this purpose, or some nice wrappers for ffmpeg.

Comment: Can you specify the video format?
Must it support web or would you have .mp4 (for example) version of the youtube video you posted.

Comment: No need to support web. Should support as many common video formats as possible but even just one (e.g. mp4) is fine.